# All the zeroes of $p(z)$ lie inside the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z) = c_0 + c_1z + c_2z^2 + \dots + c_nz^n$ where $0 \le c_0 \le c_1 \le \dots \le c_n$.  I would like to show that all zeroes of this polynomial lie inside the unit disk by applying Rouche's theorem to the polynomial $(1-z)p(z)$.  I'm not completely sure how to do this. Using the given, information I can deduce that 
$$|(1 - z)p(z)| \le |c_nz^{n+1}|$$

on the unit circle, but this doesn't really match the assumptions of Rouche's theorem.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to @DonAntonio's answer but uses Rouché's theorem. We have:
$$
(1 - z)p(z) = c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (c_k - c_{k-1}) z^k - c_n z^{n+1}
$$

Let $|z| = r > 1$, we have:

\begin{align}
\left|(1 - z)p(z) - (-c_n z^{n+1})\right| &= \left| c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (c_k - c_{k-1}) z^k \right| \\
&< \left(c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (c_k - c_{k-1})\right)\left|-z^{n+1}\right| = \left|-c_n z^{n+1}\right|
\end{align}

Thus, $(1 - z)p(z)$ and $-c_n z^{n+1}$ have the same number of zeros inside every circle $|z| = r$ for $r > 1$. But $-c_n z^{n+1}$ has $n+1$ zeros at $0$ and $(1-z)p(z)$ has $n+1$ zeros. It follows that all of the zeros of $(1-z)p(z)$ lie inside the circle $|z| = r$.

By letting $r \to 1$, we conclude that all zeros of $(1 - z)p(z)$ (and hence $p(z)$) lie in the closed unit disk. Notice that zeros can be on the unit circle as demonstrated by the polynomial $p(z) = 1 + z$.

Comment: I think you meant $|(1-z)p(z) + c_nz^{n+1}|$ on the left-hand side.  In that case, how does it follow that $(1-z)p(z)$ and $c_nz^{n+1}$ have the same number of zeroes inside the circle?

Comment: @Brian Thanks for spotting that. I fixed it. Rouché's theorem is still applicable to $(1-z)p(z)$ and $-c_nz^{n+1}$.

Comment: You showed all zeros of P(z) are in the closed unit disc. You must prove all zeros are in the open unit disc.

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$t(z):=(1-z)p(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-c_{k-1})z^k+c_0-c_nz^{n+1}$$

Let $\,w\in\Bbb C\;,\;\;|w|>1\,$ be a root of $\,p(z)\,$ and, thus, also of $\,t(z)\,$:

$$c_n|w^{n+1}|=\left|c_0+\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-c_{k-1})w^k\right|\le c_0+\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-c_{k-1})|w|^k<$$

$$<c_0|w|^n+\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-c_{k-1})|w|^n=c_n|w|^n$$

so we got:

$$c_n|w|^{n+1}<c_n|w|^n\Longrightarrow|w|<1\ldots\text{contradiction}$$

Polish and end the argument now.

Comment: I don't see how this hint helps at all.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a nice relation between the roots of $p(z)$ and $(1-z)p(z)+c_nz^{n+1}$.

Comment: Rouche's theorem as presented here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RouchesTheorem.html requires the inequality to be strict, so I'm not sure how I can apply it.

Comment: As many other times I misread the question's wording, yet the very same wording can actually help. I shall edit in a while.

Comment: I really went astray because of the Rouche's Theorem mentioning in the OP...

Comment: @user66495 , read now my answer.