# All roots of polynomial inside the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328850/all-the-zeroes-of-pz-lie-inside-the-unit-disk) that for a polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n$ with $0<a_0\leq a_1\leq...\leq a_n$ all roots are in the closed unit disk.

What condition do we need to get that all roots are in the open unit disc? I was thinking that maybe some $a_i\neq a_{i+1}$. But I don't know how to prove that?

Answer (score 4):

The result you mention is known as the Eneström-Kakeya theorem.  Necessary and sufficient conditions for when the roots of the polynomial lie on the boundary of the region are given by Anderson, Saff, and Varga in the paper

> N. Anderson, E. B. Saff, and R. S. Varga, *On the Eneström-Kakeya theorem and its sharpness*, Linear Algebra Appl. **28** (1979), 5-16.

The paper is freely available from Varga's website [here](http://www.math.kent.edu/~varga/pub.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sufficient condition: Assume that $0 < a_0 < \dots < a_n$.  Set $\tilde p(z) = p(rz)$. Then for $r < 1$, sufficiently close to 1, $\tilde p$ satisfies the conditions in your original post and hence all zeroes of $\tilde p$ are in the unit disk, implying that all zeroes of $p$ are in the disk with radius $r$.